# How to convert a single character into Scala's Char object?

Tags: scala, char, type-conversion, character, arrays

What is the simplest and the most concise method of converting a single character into **Scala**'s **Char** object?

I have found the following solution, but somehow it seems unsatisfying to me, as I believe it should have been possible to resolve this problem in a more elegant **Scala**-way without using unnecessary conversions and array-specific operations:

```
scala> "A".toCharArray.head
res0: Char = A
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are a huge number of ways of doing this.  Here are a few:

```
'A'               // Why not just write a char to begin with?

"A"(0)            // Think of "A" like an array--this is fast
"A".charAt(0)     // This is what you'd do in Java--also fast

"A".head          // Think of "A" like a list--a little slower
"A".headOption    // Produces Option[Char], useful if the string might be empty
```

If you use Scala much, the `.head` version is the cleanest and clearest; no messy stuff with numbers that might get off by one or which have to be thought about.  But if you really need to do this a lot, `head` runs through a generic interface that has to box the char, while `.charAt(0)` and `(0)` do not, so the latter are about 3x faster.

Answer (score 2):

You can use scala's [charAt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29).

```
scala> var a = "this"
a: String = this

scala> a.charAt(0)
res3: Char = t
```

Additionally, the following is valid and may be what you are looking for:

```
scala> "a".charAt(0)
res4: Char = a
```